# Enumerating the image of an integer matrix applied to a lattice

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, integer-lattices

Let $A\in\mathbb{Z}^{n \times m}$ and $x\in \mathbb{Z}^m$. Also suppose we are given $l,u\in\mathbb{Z}^m$. I would like to efficiently enumerate
$$\{Ax \,|\, l_i \le x_i \le u_i \text{ for all } i\}$$

The subscript $i$ refers to the $i^\text{th}$ element of the vector.

$A$ is not necessarily of full rank, so the problem is nontrivial.

Is there a simple algorithm for this problem? Even just a reference would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What constitutes efficiency? The set you're hoping to enumerate has, in the general case, $J = \pi (u_i - l_i)$ entries, each with $n$ entries, so simply writing down the set requires time $Jn$ in the worst case.

Comment: The naiive approach is to enumerate all of the $x$, and compute $Ax$ for each $x$. However, if $A$ is not of full rank, then many of the possible $x$ produce the same value of $Ax$. I would like the complexity of the algorithm to scale with the size of the image and not with the size of the domain.

Comment: "However, if $A$ is not of full rank, then many of the possible $x$ produce the same value of $Ax$" is false in general, although it may be true for some particular bounds. Example: $A = \pmatrix{10 & 1 \\ 20 & 2}$, $0 \le x \le 2, 0 \le y \le 3$. In view of this, I tend to doubt that there's a simple output-dependent algorithm.

Comment: Could you provide more details on the context of the problem? I.e. what sizes are $m$, $n$,  and the lattice? Is the rank much smaller than $\min(m,n)$? If $A$ is big enough and the rank is small enough there may be heuristic algorithms that work.